# What is the difference between Features in Server level and site level in IIS7.5

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, iis-7.5, user-management, iis

I am having trouble connecting with IIS_manager created users to my default FTP site.

I followed the guide at http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/321/configure-ftp-with-iis-7-manager-authentication/ (as many of us did) but I keep getting error 530 when logging with the only user I created.

Further investigation got me to an important question.

When looking at the root features of my server (IIS 7.5) there are duplicate features for FTP Authentication, FTP Authorization, and more (the same features are also available for the FTP_site iteslef).

My question: What is the difference?  It clearly states NOT to set up properties on the server level, but to select a specific site and grant user access to it. so why are these features there?

I am trying to solve my 530 connection error, but I want to learn a bit more on how and what are the features and their meanings.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties at the server level are global for the entire server; all sites will inherit them.  It's possible to override them at the site level.

Properties at the site level are specific to that site.

Different server configurations have different requirements.  Server level properties can be useful in some circumstances, but are extremely dangerous in others.  You want to be careful with them.  Especially in environments such as large shared hosting with many autonomous sites.  Take, for example, security set at the server level.  That would be monumentally bad in a large shared hosting environment.

Comment: So for my solution, as I only have 1 FTP server and 1 Web site, I will leave the global settings empty, and set only the site specific settings.  thanks